# lambda function to sum products of values from a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda

```
my_dict = {'a1':2,'a2':3,'b1':1,'b2':5,'b3':8}
```

I want to sum the products of labels 'a' and 'b' with the same numbers.

```
result = a1*b1 + a2*b2
```

note: b3 is ignored, since it has no corresponding a3.

my code:

```
result = sum (lambda x * y, if str(key)[0] == a and str(key)[0] ==b and str(key)[1] == str(key)[1], my_dict)
```

Comment: And your question is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have enough logic here that you should *probably* break out your filter into a separate function:

```
my_dict = {'a1':2,'a2':3,'b1':1,'b2':5,'b3':8}

def filtered(d):
    for key in d:
        if not key.startswith('a'):
            continue

        b_key = "b" + key[1:]

        if b_key not in d:
            continue

        yield d[key], d[b_key]

sum(a * b for a, b in filtered(my_dict))
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'startswith'

Comment: @Selvam - when I run the code above I get 17, not an `AttributeError`.  You may want to ask a new question with your new code.

Comment: Thank you Sean. I applied another inefficient method of splitting my_dict into 2 separate a and b dictionaries. I have moved on to other assignments.

Answer (score 1):

```
my_dict = {'a1':2,'a2':3,'b1':1,'b2':5,'b3':8}
result = 0

for i in range(1, (len(my_dict) + 1) / 2):
    if not my_dict.has_key("a" + str(i)) \
        or not my_dict.has_key("b" + str(i)):
        break
    result += my_dict["a" + str(i)] * my_dict["b" + str(i)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import combinations
mydict={'a1':2,'a2':3,'b1':1,'b2':5,'b3':8}

result=sum(mydict[x]*mydict[y] for x,y in combinations(mydict.keys(),2) if x[1]==y[1])
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'

Comment: What list are you referring to? I just reran the code and it returned 17, as it's supposed to. And I see you also objected to @jamylak 's code, but it also works. What version of python are you using?

Comment: My apologies. my_dict is as follows: <type 'list'> ;[{u'a10': 33}, {u'a13': 26}, {u'a14': 95}, {u'b03': 28}, {u'b13': 12}, {u'b23': 3}, {u'b43': 69}]

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import defaultdict
from functools import reduce
from operator import mul

my_dict = {'a1':2,'a2':3,'b1':1,'b2':5,'b3':8}

D = defaultdict(dict)

for k in my_dict:
    a, b = k
    D[b][a] = my_dict[k]

print sum(reduce(mul, d.values()) for d in D.values() if len(d) >= 2)
```

---

```
17
```

Comment: a, b = k // valueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Comment: My apologies. my_dict is as follows: <type 'list'> ;[{u'a10': 33}, {u'a13': 26}, {u'a14': 95}, {u'b03': 28}, {u'b13': 12}, {u'b23': 3}, {u'b43': 69}]